# Highlight two bar graphs at the same time with Flot charts

Tags: javascript, flot

I have two bar graphs. How can i highlight one bar graph and it highlights similar data on 
the other bar graph using Flot. This is what i have tried. The code changes below change the colour of the second graph appropriately however the chart does not show the colour changes

```
 $("chart").bind('plothover', function (event, pos, item){
     if (item != null) {
       if (previousPoint != item.datapoint) {
         previousPoint = item.datapoint;
         pGraph.setData(datas[item.dataIndex].color = "#FF0000");
         pGraph.draw();
       } else {
         pGraph.setData(datas[item.dataIndex].color = "#0066FF");
         pGraph.draw();
       }
     } else {
       previousPoint = null;
     }
 });
```

Comment: Uhmm What is you problem? What have you tried? What is the error message?

Comment: A little more detail would probably help. Can you show some code?

Comment: Sorry i have added code.